# realation among jos_category, jos_menu and jos_content in joomla

Tags: mysql, joomla, mysql-workbench, joomla-dbo

I have moved a joomla site to wordpress with fg joomla to wordpress (wordpress plugin) free version. Now i want to get the list of all of the content(articles) with their id, link, path and alias. 
I am new with joomla so i also want to know the difference between the alias on new article and the alias which we give at the time to add it in menu item. 
Thank in advance.
Can anybody also tell me the common attribute among the jos_categories, jos_menu and jos_content to join the table and find the list of all articles with id, alias, path and link?

Answer (score 0):

The articles of joomla sites and its all required details can be found on the `#__content`  and `#__categories` tables .

The article id, alias(path and links) is the url of the article.

`#__content` table have `catid` that connect which category those articles are (`id` in `#__categories`).

There is no direct connection between `#__menu` and `#__content`. the Joomla site may use an article link on the menu system with url or single article type those you can find on `#__menu` table with `link` field like `com_content` or something.

When you are migrating to WordPress all articles you can consider as post and its link(alias) as WordPress permalink

Hope it make sense..

Comment: yes i got all articles as post and alias as slug but i think in joomla we can have two alias fro the same article. one which is assigned at the time of article publish and other is at the time when we add that article in any menu

Comment: for single articles you can't give another link from menu, its used for blogs,category list views. not for single article so it have only one alias for these types.

Comment: thanks for the comment but i notice this thing there. Ex- i have created a article volunteer time off and choose alias volunteer-time-off but when i add this article in menu there i also get the option to choose alias and i use VTO there. 
So now the link is http://mysitename.com/vto

Comment: @vipuljain you are right from menu its possible. In this case the article alias are considered as expired link and keep on #__redirect_links table and when the user requesting for this url automatically redirect to new url in your case vto (Its done by Joomla System redirect plugin)

Comment: thanks for the details but as per your previous comment i make a query  - select  t1.id,  t1.title , t1.alias, t1.catid, t2.title, t2.alias, t2.path, jos_menu.alias, jos_menu.link, jos_menu.path FROM jos_content AS t1 left JOIN jos_categories AS t2 ON t1.catid = t2.id left join jos_menu ON (jos_menu.path = t2.path || jos_menu.alias = t1.alias) order by t1.id
Would you like to add your comment on this?